# Error running discord bot with discord.js-musicbot-addon: Cannot find module 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Recently, after installing discord.js-musicbot-addon on a discord.js bot of mine, I seem to get this error whenever I try to run it:

```
PS O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot> node main.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'
Require stack:
- O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info-extras.js
- O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js
- O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\index.js
- O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\index.js
- O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\main.js
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (O:\Om\Discord Bots\BikerBot\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js-musicbot-addon[24m\node_modules\[4mytdl-core[24m\lib\info-extras.js:5:21)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: [
    [32m'O:\\Om\\Discord Bots\\BikerBot\\node_modules\\discord.js-musicbot-addon\\node_modules\\ytdl-core\\lib\\info-extras.js'[39m,
    [32m'O:\\Om\\Discord Bots\\BikerBot\\node_modules\\discord.js-musicbot-addon\\node_modules\\ytdl-core\\lib\\info.js'[39m,
    [32m'O:\\Om\\Discord Bots\\BikerBot\\node_modules\\discord.js-musicbot-addon\\node_modules\\ytdl-core\\lib\\index.js'[39m,
    [32m'O:\\Om\\Discord Bots\\BikerBot\\node_modules\\discord.js-musicbot-addon\\index.js'[39m,
    [32m'O:\\Om\\Discord Bots\\BikerBot\\main.js'[39m
  ]
}
```

I have tried to reinstall m3u8stream, but this does not seem to fix the problem. You can view my source code here: https://github.com/reachomk/BikerBot/tree/test

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to also install parse-time in package.json, I asked a similar question and got this answer. 
also do

```
const parseTime   = require('m3u8stream/dist/parse-time');
```

in your main.js in your GitHub
answer based off of https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/pull/520/commits/dd1c93150e175e8e9bea4a6035348794181caf73

Comment: also do ```const m3u8stream  = require('m3u8stream')``` In your main.js